Boundary condition for friction on stress tensor
I want a boundary condition for the stress tensor for limiting friction. The general equation for this is $F=\mu R$. I want to investigate this on an interface. If I have a material being deformed, and being moved along, so I have to include friction. So I did a simple model of friction, consider a small blob of density $\rho$ and volume $dV$. The resultant force is $R=mg$, so the frictional force is $F=\mu mg=\mu\rho gdV$, so the force per unit volume is $\mu\rho g$, in terms of the stress tensor this will be $$\hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot\boldsymbol{\sigma}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{t}}=\mu\rho g$$
How is my reasoning here?
